# Creating a 1D axes in a 3D scene - Manim

Tags: python, axis, manim

so I'm trying to create a 1d axes and I'm failing. what I'm trying to achieve is a line with a tip that is numbered correctly and I zoom in the camera so that it shows a 2D view of the axes, and then I change the camera orientation and it rotates around the 1D axes. How can I achieve the 1D axes ?

I tried to set the length of one axis to zero but that didn't work because the tip was sticking out !
`axes = Axes( x_length=10, y_length=0,  )`
I tried to hide it's tip but I didn't find a way!

Comment: Can you share a minimal working example of how you're trying to do it? Some code that allows us to see where you might have something wrong or how you're focusing your efforts to solve it. check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info on how to help us help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NumberLine` gives you a proper 1D-axis
[ManimCE documentation](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.graphing.number_line.NumberLine.html?highlight=numberline)

[image]

Even though I don't quite understand what you exactly want to do...